# Why does XlsxWriter border box merges my string cell to the corner when the actual corner cell contains empty string

Tags: string, border, xlsxwriter, box

let's use an example df as following:

```
a     b        c   d
"hi"  "Tom,"   ""  ""
"how" "are"    ""  ""
"you" "doing?" ""  ""
```

I'm trying to export this to Excel with xlsxwriter and I would like to put a border around the entire dataframe using the following code:
https://gist.github.com/pankaj28843/d8c9c548a5a761be7ae6

When I do this I get the square border exactly as desired but the cell with "Tom" is dragged out over c and d, as if I used merge. This makes it look like this:

```
"hi"       "Tom,"
"how" "are"    ""  ""
"you" "doing?" ""  ""
```

Why does this happen, why can't I just put a border around the corner cell with "".

I checked and if I put a character in the string of columnn d, row 0 all cells stay in place like they should without the merge effect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now by replacing all empty strings "", with a space string " " but would still like to understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_center_across

In my case, the issue was related to the 'center_across' formatting attribute. This was being set to True, resulting in formats with a 'text_h_align' value of 6. I would iterate through your workbook's formats and verify the final 'text_h_align' in each.

I noticed the undesired merging behavior after porting from xlsxwriter-1.1.5-1 on py2, to xlsxwriter-3.0.2-1 on py3 -- but didn't investigate to find out whether it was broken in previous versions or had purposefully updated. Regardless, I had redundant formatting written using the suggested merge_range method, so once I removed any 'center_across' definitions from my formats I no longer saw undesired merges.